# Создание нового датафрейма с пустыми значениями в одном из столбцов

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Загружаю файл с номерами телефонов в df, подтягиваю к нему данные из другой таблицы (магазин регистрации). В этой другой таблице есть данные не о всех номерах, соответственно образуются пустые строки. Мне нужно выделить и сохранить номера, по которым не найдено соответствие, пробую код ниже и в этой части (выделения номеров без соответствий в другой датафрейм) программа не работаем, выдает мне пустой датафрейм.

```
import pandas as pd
df_moscow_number_tele2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/k.voloshina/Documents/MSC_ 0307.csv', sep = ',')
df_moscow_number_all = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/k.voloshina/Documents/all_phone_numbers_Moscow.csv', sep = ';')
df_moscow_number_all.set_axis(['Phone','shop'],axis = 'columns',inplace = True)
df_moscow_number_tele2 = df_moscow_number_tele2.merge(df_moscow_number_all, on='Phone', how='left')
df_moscow_number_tele2['shop'].unique() #вижу, что есть пустые
df_moscow_number_tele2_nan = df_moscow_number_tele2[df_moscow_number_tele2['shop'] == '']['Phone']
```

В последней команде пробовала и просто кавычки, и кавычки с пробелом внутри, и `'nan'`, и `'null'`, `nan` и `Null`.

На вопрос об уникальном содержании столбца `'shop'` следующий вывод:

```
array(['ГИП17', 'ГИП24', 'ГИП26', 'ГИП25', nan], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать функцию `isna` и кроме того, лучше для выборки пользоваться синтаксисом `df.loc[<условие выборки>, <столбец или список столбцов>]`

```
df_moscow_number_tele2_nan = df_moscow_number_tele2.loc[df_moscow_number_tele2['shop'].isna(), 'Phone']
```

Comment: помогло, спасибо!

Comment: @КристинаВолошина поставьте галку слева от ответа